# Is there a way to map child entity to parent entity using parent entity field (not parent object)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to model one to many unidirectional association. I have two entities the first one (parent) is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer{
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

The second entity has many to one relation to Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address{
@Id    
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;        
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Customer customer;
```

I need to substitute property Customer in Address class by customer.id, is it possible?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @Alan Hay Because Customer is a "big" object, and I don't want to store it in memory. I know there is a lazy fetch type option in hibernate. But in this case I don't need oportunity to get information from Customer object I need only its id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use customerId field in Adress entity and join it manually with JPQL but it's not recommended and not creates foreign key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address{
@Id    
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;        

@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Long customerId;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this way hibernate doesn't create foreing key. I think best solution is to leave it as is, and rely on lazy initialization option.

Comment: There is no other way.